# onEndReached fire again and again when ListView nested in ScrollView

Tags: react-native

```
 render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.scroll_style}>
        {this._renderStoreInfo()}
        {this._renderOperatesView()}
        <View style={styles.space}/>
        <ListView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => this._renderRow(rowData, rowID)}
          renderFooter={this._renderFooter.bind(this)}
          onEndReached={this._onEndReached.bind(this)}
          onEndReachedThreshold={10} />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

the onEndReached fired again and again as soon as it was mounted. but I do not scroll(pull up) the listview.

Answer (score 3):

There's currently an issue with `ListView` inside `ScrollView`, as both have to share the scroll.

It's possible to move what you'd like displayed above the `ListView` into `ListView` header (`renderHeader` method), and remove `ScrollView` - this avoids nested scroll components:

```
getPageHeader() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this._renderStoreInfo()}
      {this._renderOperatesView()}
      <View style={styles.space}/>
    </View>   
  )
}

render() {
  return (
      <ListView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderHeader={() => this.getPageHeader()}
        renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => this._renderRow(rowData, rowID)}
        renderFooter={this._renderFooter.bind(this)}
        onEndReached={this._onEndReached.bind(this)}
        onEndReachedThreshold={10} />
  );
}
```

It's possible that this issue will be fixed in the near future.

Comment: Yup you are right, ListView inside ScrollView acts crazy

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience. 
Just replace `<ScrollView>` with `<View>` , then the onEndReached function will work great.
ListView will have scroll-bar itself when your dataSource data over the current screen. 
You don't need to use scrollView in the case.